# Android toast troubles

Tags: android

I need to make a simple android app as a part of my school homework. The app should basically display a picture and a short text about three athletes (fighters in my case) and one of there quotes in a form of a toast. As an android noob I think I came far on my own, but now I just need some help to finish. I did the text and image part, now comes the toast thingy. The app displays toast, but all 3 of them, one after the other. I just want it to display a toast related to a fighter the user clicked, not all three of them. Anyway, here is the code:

Any ideas? Thanks :)

```
package com.example.skvik.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
View.OnClickListener{
TextView tvHeaderMessage;
private static final
String qmirko = "Right leg hospital, left leg cemetery";
String qfedor = "I don't think about fights that didn't happen.";
String qminotauro = "Every time you lose, it's good because you see        
something is amiss. The guy who's on top with no effort just settles.";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeUI();
    initializeUI1();
    initializeUI2();
}

private void initializeUI2() {
    this.tvHeaderMessage = findViewById(R. id. fedor);
    this.tvHeaderMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initializeUI1() {
    this.tvHeaderMessage = findViewById(R. id. minotauro);
    this.tvHeaderMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initializeUI() {
    this.tvHeaderMessage = findViewById(R. id. tvmirko);
    this.tvHeaderMessage.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View view) {
    this.displayToast(qmirko);
    this.displayToast(qfedor);
    this.displayToast(qminotauro);
}
private void displayToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: You can work in your **onClick** method and check the *id* of the *view* (view.getId()) that sent the "onClick" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check which view has been clicked. e.g.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.qmirko) displayToast(qmirko);
    else if(view.getId() ...)
    // and so on

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and assign different callback for each view rather 1 for all of them:

```
private void initializeUI1() {
    findViewById(R. id. minotauro).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity.displayToast(qminotauro);
    }});
}
```